# Incorporating polygons into Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Part of my web application will allow users to click on a certain territory of a map and have it highlight that section in the Google Maps that I have on the page. This is pretty standard on a lot of websites, but I'm having a hard time with the amount of data that's there.

I'm trying to generate data from http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/, which provides me several output options for actual coordinates that I want to turn into polygons, but exporting the WKT, GeoJSON, or the KML is HUGE - 700-900 KB for EACH instance, and I don't understand how this website is able to incorporate these polygons without loading this data, (Chrome doesn't show any item over 50 KB being loaded.)

## What I'm doing NOW:

I downloaded a few of the WKT files, then used PHP to translate that into a javascript string so :

```
var coordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(1.1, 1.2),
...
new google.maps.LatLng(1.1, 1.2)
];
```

I did this with about 10 locations, saved my file, and it was 9 MB - all from these super long `coordinates` strings...

How do I do this more efficiently, as this is obviously not the way to incorporate polygon data into a dynamic map load?

Comment: What kind of polygon do you export? what information you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't translate it on serverside, the string `new google.maps.LatLng` will blow up your file.

When you use e.g. geoJSON you may  load the polygon via [`loadGeoJson`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson).

The linked page uses  geoJSON to draw the polygons(e.g. http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/686972.html loads these data: http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/686972.geojson?simplify_tolerance=0.0001  ~100KB)

Another option would be to encode each single polygon(polyline) on serverside and reassemble/decode the polygons via JS.
See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding for more details.

Comment: Oh awesome!  Thank you so much for this.  I'll figure out how this works, but the `tolerance` is really what I was looking for.  If I don't set one, the geojson is basically still the same size as my `LatLng` coordinates, but setting a higher tolerance takes out some of the midway points and shortens the entire string.  Thanks again!